# Convert array of u32 to Vec<u8> in Rust

Tags: array, comparative-review, rust, iterator

In Rust, I want to take an array of `u32` values, convert each to four bytes in big endian, and concatenate them to yield a `Vec<u8>` result. Example:

```
let input: [u32; 5] = [
    0x67452301, 0xEFCDAB89, 0x98BADCFE, 0x10325476, 0xC3D2E1F0];

(... Do some data conversion work ...)

let output: Vec<u8> = vec![
    0x67, 0x45, 0x23, 0x01,
    0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB, 0x89,
    0x98, 0xBA, 0xDC, 0xFE,
    0x10, 0x32, 0x54, 0x76,
    0xC3, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xF0,
];
```

I have several pieces of working code that all give the same answer.

Algorithm A (for-loop):

```
let mut output = Vec::<u8>::new();
for val in &input{
    output.extend_from_slice(&val.to_be_bytes());
}
```

Algorithm B (for-each):

```
let mut output = Vec::<u8>::new();
input.iter().for_each(|val| output.extend_from_slice(&val.to_be_bytes()));
```

Algorithm C (fold-append):

```
let output = input.iter().fold(Vec::<u8>::new(),
    |mut acc, val| {acc.extend_from_slice(&val.to_be_bytes()); acc});
```

Algorithm D (flat-map):

```
let output: Vec<u8> = input.iter().flat_map(|val| val.to_be_bytes().to_vec()).collect();
```

Is there an even shorter, clearer way to accomplish the task? Maybe algorithm D's `to_vec()` could be avoided somehow?

Speed is not a concern because this code only executes a few times, and the input array length is fixed at 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rust 1.53.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/06/17/Rust-1.53.0.html#intoiterator-for-arrays) (2021-06-17) introduces the `IntoIterator` for array types, which finally makes this shorter code possible:

**Algorithm E (flat-map simpler):**

```
let output: Vec<u8> = input.iter().flat_map(|val| val.to_be_bytes()).collect();
```

(This is based on my algorithm D, removing `.to_vec()`. I did check that algorithm E fails to compile using Rust 1.52.0.)

---

Algorithm F (not recommended, Rust 1.51.0, see [`std::array::IntoIter::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html#method.new)):

```
let output: Vec<u8> = input.iter().flat_map(|val|
    std::array::IntoIter::new(val.to_be_bytes())).collect();
```

Answer (score 3):

Algorithm A seems the clearest to me.  An improvement might be to use `Vec::with_capacity` to avoid the allocation.  Indeed, arrays in Rust are currently somewhat cumbersome to use.

My advice would be to wrap it in a function and not worry about it later on:

```rust
pub fn to_bytes(input: &[u32]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(4 * input.len());

    for value in input {
        bytes.extend(&value.to_be_bytes());
    }

    bytes
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn to_bytes() {
        use super::*;

        assert_eq!(to_bytes(&[]), &[]);

        let input = &[0x67452301, 0xEFCDAB89, 0x98BADCFE, 0x10325476, 0xC3D2E1F0];
        let output = &[
            0x67, 0x45, 0x23, 0x01, 0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB, 0x89, 0x98, 0xBA, 0xDC, 0xFE, 0x10, 0x32,
            0x54, 0x76, 0xC3, 0xD2, 0xE1, 0xF0,
        ];

        assert_eq!(to_bytes(input), output);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b416f84cab0a1051cbac22ad81e03f7))